# Impala converting input time to null during daylight savings switch

Tags: hadoop, hiveql, impala

Came across a strange issue where in when converting a timestamp from PST to GMT, to_utc_timestamp function is returning blank. I could see that this happening for an hour range only on the day daylight savings were switched off in US.

```
Query: select to_utc_timestamp(cast('2017-11-05 01:00:00' as timestamp),'PST')

Query: select to_utc_timestamp(cast('2017-11-05 01:59:59' as timestamp),'PST')
```

Above queries return blank output.

However the same things works fine in hive:

```
Query: select to_utc_timestamp(cast('2017-11-05 01:00:00' as timestamp),'PST')
OK
2017-11-05 09:00:00
Query: select to_utc_timestamp(cast('2017-11-05 01:59:59' as timestamp),'PST')
OK
2017-11-05 09:59:59
```

Need help understanding reason for the same and also how to work around this issue using Impala query itself.

Impala Version - v2.7.0 on CDH 5.10

Hive version - 1.1.0 on CDH 5.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the same Impala and CDH versions as you, and the same bug presents. This workaround would get the right answer in Impala though:

```
select case 
    when 
        cast('2017-11-05 01:00:00' as timestamp) >= '2017-11-05 01:00:00' and 
        cast('2017-11-05 01:00:00' as timestamp) <= '2017-11-05 01:59:59' 
    then 
        hours_sub(to_utc_timestamp(hours_add('2017-11-05 01:00:00', 1), 'PST'), 1)
    else 
        to_utc_timestamp(cast('2017-11-05 01:00:00' as timestamp), 'PST') end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming the issue. Also the workaround works for me as suggested.